# Паттерн Visitor и правила ООП

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, инкапсуляция

Пусть есть класс:

```
class A
{
private:
    int x;
    ...
};
```

И некоторый контейнер `Container<A>` с методом `Container<A>::accept<VisitorT>(const VisitorT visitor)`

Пусть есть конкретный visitor, в котором нужно установить поля класса A.

```
void concrete_visitor(A& a)
{
   a.x = 1;
}
```

Но поле x приватное. Если сделать его публичным, то это будет нарушением ООП? Если с точки зрения книги Object Thinking сеттеры и геттеры - тоже нарушение инкапсуляции.

Как правильно согласовать такое поведение не нарушив принципов ООП? При этом не используя friend, ведь посетителем может быть лямбда и их может быть большое количество.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Паттерн Посетитель (Visitor) позволяет определить операцию для объектов других классов **без изменения этих классов**.

Comment: не понятно, как этот ответ связан с вопросом...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Я про изменение классов без нарушения ООП и спрашивал.

Comment: @Fat-Zer В чем, по вашему состоит вопрос автора?

Comment: @OlegUP, нормальное решение — сделать сеттер/геттер и ООП будет в порядке... почему какая-то книга называет это «нарушением инкапсуляции» без цитаты/контекста я трактовать не возьмусь...  а если это сторонний класс, который ни при каких обстоятельствах не подлежит изменению, то, само собой, посетитель и не сможет изменть это поле...

Comment: @ВадимАлександру, я подозреваю, что OP задал вопрос исходя из неверных предпосылок... так что затрудняюсь сказать, в чём именно его смысл...